# How to create a transparent clipping mask?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I want to create an image that has the text as transparent like this (imagining that black is transparent)

[image]

So in photoshop I have tried selecting 'color range' and choosing the white and then getting the inverse selection and deleting it from a new white layer. But this comes out very pixelated like this (I have put a black layer underneath to show through the transparence):

[image]

How can I do this without the pixelated edges? The ideal situation here would be if there was a 'transparent clipping mask'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one (of the many) ways you could do this:

1. In the `Channels` panel (next to the `Layers` panel by default) at the bottom click the dotted circle ('Load channel as selection') [image: Load channel as selection button]
2. Then click back to `Layers` and click the 'Add layer mask' button at the bottom [image: Add layer mask button]

By doing this I got: (with an image layer underneath)

[image]

**EDIT:**

If the text layer is a vector layer, you can also put the image you want to use on top of the text layer, then hold the `Alt` key and click on the line that separates the layers:

[image: Screenshot]

That method allows the text to be edited and the overlay will update dynamically.

Comment: The point is that. I want to be able to add any image bellow it. Not a pre defined one. That is why I can't use a clipping mask as you have used above! But the first method works perfectly!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + click on the **T** icon of the text layer in the Layers palette. This creates a selection around the text. Then click the Add Layer Mask at the bottom of the palette. Et voilà.